# How do i delete duplicate values from a table by reatining its occurance once

Tags: sql

There is an EMPLOYEE Table with following data

```
NAME SALARY
A     100
A     100
B     200
C     300
C     300
D     400
```

please provide me with the quert to delete the duplicates by retaining the occurance once i.e the table has to look like below after performing delete operation

```
NAME SALARY
A     100
B     200
C     300
D     400
```

Comment: SO is not your personal code writing service. So what have you tried?

Comment: which DBMS you are using?

Comment: Do you have an `id` column?

Comment: You have to specify more details. Do you want distinct values on column NAME or on both column? What if you have another record like this: A **200**? In case which you describe simple query is enough: SELECT DISTINCT NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE.

Comment: No primary key? Poor db design... Create a copy of the table, do `insert into copytable select * from originaltable`. Either drop original table and rename copytable, or delete from originaltable and insert into originaltable select * from copytable.

Comment: This was one of the questions asked in interview they where just expecting query to removed the duplicates please

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple to delete duplicate rows by following query..

```
WITH tblTemp as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Salary ORDER BY Name)
   As RowNumber,* FROM youtablename
)
DELETE FROM tblTemp where RowNumber >1
```

for one more trick check the site:---http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/159881/How-to-remove-duplicate-rows-in-SQL-Server-wh

Comment: How do you know that OP's RDBMS supports cte and windowed functions?

Comment: I am a tester and i just have basic knowledge of SQL This was one of the questions asked in interview they where just expecting query to removed the duplicates